# Save Datetime in UTC, view/query in User's timezone in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

What is the standard for saving times in one zone and viewing them in another?  I have this in my `environment.rb`:

```
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
```

But I want to render it, and do queries like "all posts created today" in their timezone, where `beginning_of_day` returns the beginning of the day in their timezone rather than UTC.  Is rails already handling the conversion in the background?

Here's the issue:

```
@now = Time.now
 => Wed Jan 26 09:50:04 -0600 2011 
User.count(:conditions => ["created_at > ?", @now])
  SQL (1.3ms)   SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM `users` WHERE (created_at > '2011-01-26 09:50:04') 
 => 1 
@now = Time.now.utc
 => Wed Jan 26 15:50:10 UTC 2011 
User.count(:conditions => ["created_at > ?", @now])
  SQL (1.2ms)   SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM `users` WHERE (created_at > '2011-01-26 15:50:10') 
 => 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ActiveSupport has built-in methods to display time values in any time zone. Typically you'd add a `time_zone` column to your User model and set it to the user's preferred zone.

```
@user.update_attribute(:time_zone,'Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
```

Then when displaying a time value, set the zone to the user's zone.

```
Time.zone = @user.time_zone
Time.zone.now # shows current time according to @user.time_zone
```

One approach is to set this in `ApplicationController` so it is done for each request:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_time_zone

  def set_time_zone
    Time.zone = current_user.time_zone if current_user
  end
end
```

Note: see the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) under ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone